# How to get the Object ID in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I tried to find the objectID in the background so I can successfully unpin and delete the object in the background. However the objectID is for some reason returning a nil value and thus resulting in the app to crash.

Here is some code -

(imagesToDelete is an array of PFFile)

```
      for object in imagesToDelete
      {
            var imageObject = PFObject(className: "img")
            imageObject["theImg"] = object
               //Object ID Returns nil
             var objID = imageObject.objectId

            //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while
            imageObject.removeObjectForKey(objID!)
            imageObject.unpinInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil
                {
                    imageObject.deleteEventually()
                    println("Objects deleted!")
                } 
               else 
                {
                    println(error)
                }

            })

        }
```

Comment: are you download straight from parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  **var objID = imageObject.objectId** will never work because imageObject is an instance of PFObject, so you could only save a particular id with that object or use the default objectID provided by parse.
Example:

```
 // let's save an object using a specific id                
   var savingObject = PFObject(classname:"")
   savingObject["id"] = 123213
   // then you save this object to parse
```

When it comes to delete that object you must query the object in the background using **PFQuery** then you could get that our specific **id** or the default id **objectId** from parse.

Example:

```
   // let's query and delete that object         
      var query = PFQuery(classname:"")
      query.whereKey("id", equalTo:123213)
      // then you use that findObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() method then delete the object.
```

**Even Though you are saving locally, you pretty much use the same concept** Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you!! I got everything working. I will up vote the answer for you!!